# Why is mtDNA not labelled as such for many organisms?

Tags: genome, sequence-annotation, reference-genome, mtdna

[Also posted on biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9589320/)

While I was searching the genomes of some eukariotic organisms (fungi,plants,protists) even though I knew that they had mitochondrial DNA,when I searched their genome structure I couldn't find any "chromosome" labeled as "mtDNA". Here I give some links of genomes that show this:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/gdv/browser/genome/?id=GCF_016861865.1
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/gdv/browser/genome/?id=GCF_009556855.1

Why does this happens? How can I find if the mtDNA sequence is inluded in these "chromosomes"?

Comment: Note how in https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/datasets/genome/GCF_016861865.1/, the number of "organelles" is listed as 0 for RefSeq but 1 in GenBank. I would guess you can find a mitochondrial sequence in GenBank.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious answer is wet-lab rather than bioinformatics: mtDNA can get removed in the DNA extraction process. As a control group, in bacterial drug-resistance studies the plasmids are frequently lost. mtDNA at ~15KB is smaller than a regular bacterial plasmid.

On the bioinformatics front there would be an issue about reference genome assemblies as well, i.e. if mtDNA genome isn't present then it will not appear as a separate genome.